# Conversion of one form to another electrostatic integral

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I was learning about *Electrostatic Potential*.

First they introduced,

$\overrightarrow E(\overrightarrow r) = -\nabla \phi(\overrightarrow r)  \quad\quad-(eq \;i)$

I understood the above equation because both are equal to *zero*.

But as I was reading further, I came across,

$-\int^{\overrightarrow r}_{\overrightarrow r_{ref}}\overrightarrow E(\overrightarrow {r'}) \;.\;\overrightarrow {dr'}=\int^{\overrightarrow r}_{\overrightarrow r_{ref} }\nabla\phi(\overrightarrow {r'})\cdot \overrightarrow{ dr'}=\int ^{\overrightarrow r}_{\overrightarrow r_{ref}}\frac{d\phi(\overrightarrow {r'})}{dr'} \;.\;\overrightarrow{dr'}=\phi(\overrightarrow{r'})-\phi(\overrightarrow{r_{ref}})\quad\quad-(eq \;ii)$

Let me assume eq(ii) this way,

$I_1=I_2=I_3$

Now, it is pretty much obvious why $I_1=I_2$ (from eq i).

Now, what I am facing difficulty is in figuring out how $I_2=I_3$.

If we look closely at $I_2$, we find that *function of the integral* consists of $\nabla\phi$, which is nothing but *gradient*. But as far as I know, $\nabla$ consists of *partial fraction symbols* $\partial$. Now, how did $\partial$ convert into $d$ in $I_2=I_3$?

If we closely compare $I_2$ and $I_3$, we get,

$\nabla\phi(\overrightarrow{r'})=\frac{d\phi(\overrightarrow{r'})}{dr'}\;.\;\overrightarrow {dr'}$. How is this part derived? This is my confusion, Can anyone please clarify it (with derivation if possible) ?

[See this(pg1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYPez.png) [And this (pg2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcbqK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\nabla \phi ({\overrightarrow{r'}})\cdot {\overrightarrow{dr'}} &= (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x'} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y'} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z'} \hat{k}) \cdot (\vec{dx'} \hat{i} + \vec{dy'} \hat{i} + \vec{dz'} \hat{k}) \\
&= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x'} dx'+ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y'}dy' + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z'} dz' \\
 &= d\phi ({\overrightarrow{r'}})
\end{align}

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

All your integrals are *path* integrals, meaning that, in more formal terms, you would have to pick a curve $\gamma$ joining the two ends and compute

$$\int_0^1\mathbf E(\gamma(t))\cdot\dot\gamma(t)\text dt$$

In general, this integral will depend on the choice of the path $\gamma$, but if $\mathbf E$ is a conservative field, that is, there exists a scalar field $\phi$ such that $\mathbf E=\nabla\phi$, then the integral only depends on the ends of the curve $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$.